# Excel 2007 won't auto-calculate

Tags: microsoft-excel

After an upgrade from Excel 2003 to 2007, suddenly auto-calculate does not work any longer. If the user hits F2 it will correctly update all fields. Also, the calculation mode is correctly set to Automatic. Could this be a macro issue? Really not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-installing Excel 2007 after uninstalling it completely fixed the issue. Must have been a clash of libraries left over from Excel 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Excel Options" button from the windows office circle thingy.  That will bring up a new dialog box.  Down the left side will be a "Formulas" item.  Select it and then you will be graced by the caluclations stuff.  Make sure "Automatic" is selected.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: As noted in the question, calculation is set correctly to Automatic. :)

Comment: That will teach me to read! :)